# @DateTime.Now function does not work for me

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have enabled IIS on my laptop and have added a folder named MyAsp. 
In this folder I have a file named `myfirstscript.asp` with the below code.
When I run the below code I dont see the date & time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
 <html lang="en"> 
  <body> 
   <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
   <p>The Time is: @DateTime.Now()</p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use it onload???

Comment: Try this  <p>The Time is: @DateTime.Now</p>

Comment: what is your code behing c# or vb?

Comment: is this your ASPX page or pure HTML page ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_asp_date

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` is a property, not a method. You need to use `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Now()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes as below

```
 <p>The Time is: <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %></p>
```

**Html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
     <html lang="en"> 
      <body> 
       <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
        <p>The Time is: <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %></p>
     </body>
    </html>
```

> DateTime.Now.ToString();
>
> DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
>
> DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() ;
>
> DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() ;
>
> DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() ;

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the asp.net inline expressions.

```
<p>The Time is: <%= DateTime.Now %></p>
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

Answer (score 0):

If it is your **ASPX** page then you can always use :

```
<%= DateTime.Now %>
```

But If it is your pure **HTML** page then you should use javascript as mentioned below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body onload="getDate();">
    <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1> <p>The Time is: <span id="date"></span>.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function getDate() {
            alert(Date());
            document.getElementById('date').innerText = Date().toString();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```